# How to pronounce possessive plurals?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives

We have a sentence:

- Those are my brothers's bikes.

Which means:

- Those are the bikes of my brothers.

But how to say the first sentence? Do we pronounce the 's's or make the 'z' sound?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regular plurals in English end in an /s/ or /z/. If we use a possessive, genitive form of these plurals, we do not add a second /s/ or /z/. The possessive form is the same as the plural. It does not change. Also, we do not add another S in the writing:

- my brothers' bikes
- the buses' windshields
- the cats' tails

If the plural is **ir**regular, then we do add /s/ or /z/. We also add an apostrophe and a second S in the writing:

- The children's bikes
- The women's books

If the irregular plural ends in /s/ or /z/, then we add /ɪz/:

- the mice's eyesight /ðə maɪsɪz aɪsaɪt/

Comment: You might want to add how to pronounce the possessive of a name ending with S, like "James's dog is fat" (or Thomas's, or Travis's). It isn't what the OP asked, but I think it's what they really wanted to ask.

Comment: @FabioTurati Unfortunately, English isn’t entirely consistent in how those are pronounced. You’re *supposed* to add the /ɪz/, but many people don’t, and I, even though I am a native speaker and know the “rule,” find the pronunciation awkward for some names and do not always use it.

Comment: @FabioTurati Maybe you could write an answer about that? :-) [I wanted to keep my answer short and simple!]

Comment: @KRyan It's even worse than that: the Penguin Guide to Punctuation [recommends](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/possessive-of-proper-names-ending-in-s/) that "A name ending in s takes only an apostrophe if the possessive form is not pronounced with an extra s. Hence: Socrates’ philosophy [...]". As a non-native, I'd use the way it's written to know how to pronounce it, and now I'm told I should use the way it's pronounced to know how to write it? And there's a lot more to say! Maybe all of this is too much to add here, and should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @FabioTurati Yes, it would make  a very good question!

Comment: @FabioTurati Well, as a native speaker (but not a philosopher), I'd _say_ "Socrates's philosophy". so I agree with you: the Penguin Guide isn't providing a whole lot of guidance, there!

Answer (score 2):

> baiks    -    brotherz

I use a more a voiced "z" than an unvoiced "s" in "brotherz" [ToLearnEnglish.com](http://www.tolearnenglish.com/cgi2/myexam/voir2r.php?id=2734). But that is only a simple example. A fuller understanding might be found here[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics))
Not every English speaker uses the same sounds in the same places.
A start in what might be correct can be found here [Rachel's English](http://rachelsenglish.com/pronounce-plural-nouns/)
Imitating educated speech will be the best method to be sure what you are doing is correct.

Comment: Thanks for this but that's not exactly what I want. I know how to pronounce the *S,Z,IZ* sounds and but I'm exactly interested in possessives of plurals like **sisters's**, **lamps's**, **cars's**, **houses's** and etc.

Comment: @SovereignSun : The correct form of these is **sisters'**, **lamps'**, **cars'**, and **houses'**. In these cases, they are pronounced exactly like the nominative forms. So you can't tell just from the pronunciation whether or not these are possessive forms -- you will have to rely on the context.